# What is the laplace transform of $(\delta(t−π/6))u(t-π/6)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I know that  $L(f(t-a).u(t-a)) = e^{-as}.F(s)$
Does that mean the laplace transform of the above equation is $e^{-2πs}$?

Edited: sorry i meant $(\delta(t−π/6))u(t-π/6)$ not $(\delta(t−π/6))u(t-π)$ missed the 6 out when i initially asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is equal to $0$ since
$$
f(t)\delta(t-t_0)=f(t_0)\delta(t-t_0)
$$
and
$$
u({\pi\over 6}-\pi)=0
$$

Also the statement you wrote is wrong. We have
$$
L(f(t-a))=e^{-as}F(s)
$$
as long as the ROCs are treated carefully.